# Fade in & Fade out not working in the below code

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am not an excellent techie and but I came up with this code for the redirection of pages correctly.I tried executing it,but could not fix with the fade out and fade in property.

Could anyone help me out working with this functionally.

the code I used for implementation

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function delayer(){
    window.location = "../safari-index -black/page3.html"
}
//-->
$("#page").fadeOut(2000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 36000)">
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: two body tag `<body>` opening ?

Comment: and where is the `id="page"` code part? Show us the whole code

Comment: First write and format proper code so that others can give answers

Comment: Have you added `jQuery` library? Because your code does not shows any `jQuery` library. And you still have an extra `<body>` in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your fadeout in Window.load

```
$(function(){
    $("#page").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#page").fadeOut(2000); }, 30000);
});
```

And add

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

to your head tag

Comment: Open your JavaScript console and check if you see any errors - Press Ctrl-Shift-J and see the console tab. In the above code, you have not loaded the jQuery library. Add <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> in between your head tag

Comment: Yes that works too, but it starts fading so fast when i change the milliseconds, i want it to start fading out after 30 seconds.

Comment: any idea how to make fadeout start after some seconds?

Comment: Changed my answer, added setTimeout

Comment: @Arun Thank you it helpd me a lot,

But now what if i want to fade in the page and then fade out .

Comment: Have edited my answer - added $("#page").hide().fadeIn(2000); This hides the page as soon as the window loads and then fades it in. You may see a flash. To avoid that add style='display:none' to your $page tag

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jquery reference for fadein and fadeout. include this script tag in your head tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

and also remove the first body tag as you included two.

Comment: +1 Same I added in comment part of question. I think jQuery library is missing in Question Other's code.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do this:

```
$(function(){
   $(document.body).fadeOut(2000,function(){
     window.location = "../safari-index -black/page3.html"
   });
 })
```

And if you want to start the fadeout after a specifiy time, you could do this:

```
$(function(){
 var timeToWait = 1000;
 setTimeout(function(){
 $(document.body).fadeOut(2000,function(){
   window.location = "../safari-index -black/page3.html"
 });
},timeToWait )
})
```

Comment: What do youz mean with "that is not working"? Whats the error?`You can't expect people helping you without some specific informations.